# ld: main.o: in function `main': main.asm:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to `printf'

Tags: c, assembly, printf, nasm

This is my code here and when I try to link my program linker says undefined reference to printf in my code. The code is a program to check divisibilty by 2 and 8 and print numbers in loop. And im getting the error undefined reference to printf and I need the user to input an integer.  I linked it through:

```
nasm -f elf32 cw2.asm 
gcc -m32 cw2.o
```

Also, I tried online compiler also the same error

```
global main

extern printf

SECTION .data
message1: db "Enter a number: ", 0
number1: db "%d", 0
integer1: times 10 db 0 ; 32-bits integer = 10 bytes
msg db 'Divisible by 2 and 8', 0xa,0xd
len equ $ - msg
SYS_EXIT equ 1
STDOUT EQU 1
SYS_WRITE EQU 4
SECTION .bss
val2 resb 2

SECTION .text

main:

push message1
call printf
pop ebx
mov eax, 3
mov ebx, 1
mov ebx, val2
mov edx, 2
int 0x80
push val2
mov al, [val2]  

l1:
.divisble_by_2:
mov ax, [number1]
xor dx, dx
mov bx, 2
div bx
cmp dx, 0
jnz .not_divisible

.divisble_by_8:
mov ax, [number1]
xor dx, dx
mov bx, 8
div bx
cmp dx, 0
jnz .not_divisible

.print_number:
mov edx, [number1]
add edx, 48
mov [number1], edx

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, [number1]
mov edx, len
int 0x80
mov eax, .divisble_by_2
int 0x80

.not_divisible:
xor eax, eax
mov edx, [eax+len]
mov al, 1
mov esi, .divisble_by_2
mov edi, eax
mov eax, 1
int 0x80
```

The program should print numbers in loop so there is no ending to the program
Here is the error I got on linux when i tried linking
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRRxb.png)

```
ld: main.o: in function `main':
main.asm:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to `printf'
```

Comment: So how exactly do you link this and with what linker?

Comment: @Lundin I linked it through: nasm -f elf32 cw2.asm      gcc -m32 cw2.o Also, I tried online compiler also the same error

Comment: You should edit the question and such details there.

Comment: Try `call printf` -> `call _printf`

Comment: @MohammadFayad please [edit] the question and put all relevant details as well as the __verbatim__ error log into the question.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I already tried that and it also gives the same error but instead of printf it gives undefined reference to _printf

Comment: @MohammadFayad don't post pictures of text but npost text as properly formatted text. An error log is text.

Comment: The error message shown doesn't correspond to the build steps shown. There's no main.o in your build steps. Please be sure to show the exact commands and the full error messages from gcc.

Comment: Eww, `div` is totally unnecessary here.  You know your divisor, 2, is the base of the binary number system, right?  So you just need to check for the low bit being 0.  (People have told you this repeatedly on your previous questions.  This time your `div` code looks correct, just very inefficient.)

Comment: Cannot reproduce - the commands `nasm -f elf32 cw2.asm ; gcc -m32 cw2.o` complete successfully on Linux Ubuntu 20.04 x86-64.  Do you have the 32-bit development packages installed, e.g. `libc6-dev-i386` for me?

Comment: @Jabberwocky: ELF systems never decorate symbols with a leading `_`, at least Linux doesn't.